# Brother MFC-L2710DW mysteriously stopped printing

Tags: debian, cups, printer, devuan, brother

I'm trying to use Brother MFC-L2710DW multifunction printer/scanner with my 
Devuan ASCII machine (which is just like Debian Stretch but without systemd).

At first, this seemed to work: I printed a couple of test pages, I scanned, life was good. (This was over wireless with a fixed IP address for the printer.)

Now, a few days later, I'm trying to print again - and nothing gets printed! The notices which come up (I use Cinnamon, CUPS) say the job has been sent to the printer, and the queue is empty, but the printer says it's sleeping and does nothing. The printer responds to pinging to its IP address. It also manages to scan images just fine.

I tried connecting the printer via USB, and supposedly this succeeded - but again, no pages come out. I used the printer's test print function (not through the computer), and that's fine too.

Finally, I've now used my laptop (running Lubuntu 18.04) to test: Made the same installation, and a test page prints.

What's going on and how can I get my Devuan system to print again?